# factor function turning output to N/A

Tags: r

I have a very large data-set that contains reviews from Tripadvisor. I am running a Naive Bayes model to predict whether or not a review is helpful.

A review could be classified as helpful if the number of helpful reviews is > 0.

I am running into the issue that when I attempt to change my `helpful_reviews` to factor, it changes all my values to `NA` (See screenshot). Could someone tell me how to fix this?

Also, how should I best go about changing values above 1 (which are also helpful reviews) to 1, so I only have 0's and 1's?

Sample data:
`dfReviewSample <- c(1,2,2,5,3,3,4,2,5,4,6,7,7,0,9,0,9,0)`

[image: Screenshot of output]

```
dfReview <- read.csv("reviews_final.csv", row.names = 1)
dfReview$review_body <- NULL
#dfReview$helpful_votes = dfReview$helpful_votes > 0
#ifelse(dfReview$helpful_votes >= 1, dfReview$helpful_votes == 1, dfReview$helpful_votes 
==0)
dfReview$helpful_votes <- factor(dfReview$helpful_votes,
                             levels = c("No", "Yes"))
View(dfReview)
```

Comment: What is the content of `dfReview$helpful_votes`? You are creating a factor with two levels, "Yes" and "No". Any value which is not one of the factor levels will become NA.

Comment: @samR that explains the N/A. I should've thought of that! Thank you. The contents are numbers, and that's is why they changed

Comment: `as.factor(ifelse(dfReview$helpful_votes > 0, 1, 0))`